# Cant Resolve while adding fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Following [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#AddAtRuntime) I'm trying to setup a fragment but I have an error here:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragment_container, myfrag).commit();
```

> Can't resolve method add(int, com.mypackage.MyFragment)

I have a FrameLayout with a fragment_container id and MyFragment Extends Fragment... So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here... First time using fragments...

Here is my code

Main Activity:

```
public class MainFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_fragmentactivity);
        int frag = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("fragment");

        if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            if(savedInstanceState != null) return;

            MyFragment myfrag= new MyFragment();
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, myfrag).commit();

...
```

MyFragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_devicelist, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);

        listView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.lvHosts);
...
```

settings_framentactivity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: are you importing the correct Fragment-class ?

Comment: You might have to add additional tag parameter like this :getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragment_container, myfrag,"tag_name").commit();

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're importing `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` class and not `android.app.Fragment`

Comment: I am. can you tell me the difference between v4 and v7

Comment: v4 is support library which has loaders, fragment and other support to make sure it works API 4 onwards. v7 library has lots of UI related backwards compatible UI element. APIs in v7 library works API 7 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my code in my question is a bug, but written out longhand everything is fine.

```
MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```